# In what language should I write my city/country name abroad?

Tags: passports, paperwork, france, italy, languages

I'm currently filling a Italian passport request form, but I'm at a roadblock

My question is the following :

I was born in Paris, France

- Paris, France is what is written in my birth certificate and other official French papers
- Parigi, Francia is the Italian translation

A relative's Italian paper ID card mentions the French writing of the city name (Paris) but the Italian translation of France (Francia)

What should I write on my paperwork? The French original way, the Italian translation or a mix of both?

Comment: Usually you write the country name in the local language and the city or town in the original, but Paris is large and well-known enough that you shouldn't have a problem either way.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Odds are pretty high whatever you write will end up on the passport as is, so I'd suggest **you write it the way you want to see it**.

In your case, "Paris" will be universally recognized, while "Parigi" will not be.

Anecdotally, when my son was born, his birthplace was technically Obscuresuburb, which happens to share a postcode with Wellknowncity.  So I registered his place of birth as Wellknowncity, and that's what's been written on his passport ever since.

Comment: I am not sure about Italy, but some European countries use your place of birth, in the lack of some kind of numerical id for your person (e.g. social security number), as a part of the 'key' to your identity. Whatever translation you choose to use in the application, just make sure that you stick with that name in other documents to prevent someone from treating you as two identities.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Thanks for the advice. In any way, to prevent any issues, I will write the form 3 times, with three different combinations, bring them to the appointment and let them tell me which combination is accepted

Comment: Oh, consistency is _so_ important, @Tor-EinarJarnbjo! I work with end-user supplied information all the time and try to match it up to _other_ end-user supplied information and people use a wide variety of versions of their own names on different documents. Many times, I don't have a unique identifying ID list a SSN, so matching based solely on name and date of birth when one document says "Kim" and another says "Kimberly" is so much fun...

Comment: Yeah, I have to try to match people up based on what *other people* write in as their name. I have often dreamt of making it illegal to have multiple email addresses. (Despite having 3 email addresses myself.) And don't even mention changing names, like when getting married.

Comment: @FreeMan, Martha https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/ should be mandatory reading for anyone who needs to deal with names in programming/database design. (Most of it applies to addresses/streetnames too.)

Comment: @Tonny woah, thanks for that! I've seen the original list, but for some of them couldn't really think of an example. This makes it clearer!

Comment: @Tonny, thank you. That simply emphasizes the problems I've faced without offering solutions. Unfortunately, I was trying to match up what "John Doe" gave us at one time with what "Jonathan Doe" gave us at a different time, so there wasn't even necessarily operator error involved.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo *If* obtaining a Codice Fiscale (tax code) is relevant to OP, they should make sure that their tax code ends with `Z110X` (the final `X` can be any letter, is a checksum, `Z110` is the code for France). Otherwise it means they fucked up something. Unfortunately there is no way to request a specific tax code, so by the time they will be able to see if it was recorded correctly it will already be issued but at least they will know if everything is fine or not. The fact that OP was born in Paris is irrelevant for the tax code (town is only used for birth inside Italy)

Comment: And yes, absolutely be consistent with the names @NicolasFormichella If you have a middle/multiple names/surnames decide which form of your name you want to use and stick with it in every form consistently.

Comment: @GACy20 I was issued a Codice Fiscale at birth it seems, and yes it ends with `Z110Y`

Answer (score 20):

I went to my appointment at the consulate and asked the employee which form is valid.

They entered (or it was pre-entered like so) `Paris, FRANCIA` in the database (which is the same as what is in my AIRE registration) with `Paris (FRA)` written on the passport.

I believe that only the country is to be translated from original (likely in order to have a valid address that all postal services involved can understand because `Parigi` is not a French city)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post what happened!

Answer (score 0):

The data you put in the form will end up in an Italian database and checked against data written in Italian. Since cases of homonymy are very common in Italy date and place of birth constitute an important part of your ID. So, you should write the Italian name of the city.

If the form data will be entered manually probably the employee will translate the name, but chances are that it will be scanned and entered automatically, then an employee may or may not fix it.

Comment: This makes no sense.  Passports are used and checked overseas, not in Italy.

Comment: @lambshaanxy An application for a passport means that the authorities do some background checks to verify that the applicant has no criminal records, pending debts and so on. Most searches are carried on via Codice Fiscale, a unique identifier initially created for tax reason, but then used for all the government services. That code is generated taking the place of birth into account. Actually I can't remember whether for people born abroad they use the name of the city or the country, but with the Italian bureaucracy you better make things as simple as possible.